# texture to geometry: is it possible

Tags: texturing

is it possible for me to use the values/colours in an image texture/vornoi to cut a mesh into pieces. eg light grey is split into one section, black another, white another. etc. if not, what alternatives should I try looking into?

Comment: **Yes, it's possible but it has it cons..
follow this tutorial and instead of using a procudural texture, use your own image texture**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY